# Mysql query to get total current sales of each product by month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It is my sql code i want to show the Total SUM of current-sales by month of each product, in this image we can see the Total result in october of pro_id =175, i want to show the entry of every month of each product, is there any loop for many products?  I will show the result in html table using php.

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(`order_date`), SUM(`current-sales`) AS TotalCS,  `nsp`, `pro_id`
FROM `orders` 
WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2017 AND MONTH(order_date) = 10
  AND pro_id = 175
```

[Result by October](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53API.png)

Comment: You need to do GROUP BY!

Comment: for each product? if products increases what will i do?

Comment: what is `nsp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`. With this, you'll get the sum of the current sell of each pro_id by the months of 2017

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(order_date), SUM(current-sales) AS TotalCS, pro_id
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(order_date), pro_id, nsp
```

Comment: This works only if you have `STRICT` option off. Also be carefull you will get  a random nsp.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I understand for the nsp i just copy paste and made a mistake, but i don't understand why you'll need strict mode off? Isn't it just for data changing queries?

Comment: sorry I mean `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` now is the default setting on MySQL
`

Comment: NSP is Net Sale Price. Which is different of every different product but same of every same product

Comment: @user3030814 I edited my answer so you'll see the good one if the NSP is linked to pro_id

Answer (score 0):

Try datepart function this should work:

```
SELECT datepart('month','order_date'), SUM(`current-sales`) AS TotalCS, `nsp`, `pro_id` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE datepart('year','order_date') = '2017' AND datepart('month','order_date')= '10' AND pro_id = 175
```

Result by October

```
SELECT datepart('month','order_date'), SUM(`current-sales`) AS TotalCS, `nsp`, `pro_id` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE datepart('year','order_date') = '2017' AND datepart('month','order_date')= '10' AND
Group by datepart('month','order_date');
```

For all month

Comment: datepart is not supporting in mysql database showing this error. #1305 - FUNCTION del.datepart does not exist

Comment: Use this instead of datepart function:

EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_column)